# Where are all the star stones?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I seem to be missing a few as I near the end of the game.  Where can I find all the star stones so I can see which ones I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That i'm aware of there are 16 star stones (maybe there is more) but theses are the ones i know (got a list from here http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/672174-divinity-original-sin/69661235 to make it easy)

1 - Doctors office - make a choice

2 - Ransacked inn room

3 - Black cove pirate treasure box

4 - Braccus's tomb

5 - N exit from first area (fire zone)

6 - Hiberium prison inside an iron maiden (destroy it)

7 - King Boreus Treasure room

8 - Immaculate trial stone

9 & 10 - Basement of the immaculte church

11 - Totem in the goblem village (destroy it)

12 - Marando one (inside his hidden place, its a shard but works the same)

13 - Knights tomb E of hunters edge

14 - In the statue behind cassandras remains

15 - Source temple behind a mirror

16 - Immaculate trial area (cassandra's blood dungeon)

Thanx for Crimson Phanton (http://www.gamefaqs.com/users/Crimson+Phantom/boards)
for the post on gamefaqs

Comment: does having all 16 star stones fully unlock the base?  If it does then that's all I really care about.

Comment: @z' 12 are needed to fully unlock the base (and complete the game). The rooms are observatory, hall of heros, bedroom, 4x elementals, secrets vendor, armory, respec guy, equipment trader, chapel. The last portal is apparently for use by party animals only, the slot below it is empty, and the tree up the stairs is opened up for the final boss.